# How to correctly multiline a Yaml List

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, jwt

I'm trying to set a public key as environment variable inside my *docker-compose.yaml* file.

I understand we have 2 different syntax we can use (can't use both at same time):
One is a *YAML mapping*, which uses the syntax `key: value`:

```
environment:  
  key: value
  key2: value2
  // And this is how we Muliline
  publicKey: |-
    -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
    UAdhusaudu89Ajdsdoskdosadk*(Sd98798da
    kaosdkOKdoksaoKDOaksdo98d7868sadajidas
```

And we also have the `YAML list` syntax, which uses the syntax `var = value`:

```
environment:
  key=value
```

But how may I successfully **multiline using YAML list syntax?**
I need to get the *line breaks (\n)* too.

When I try to read the environment variable I get a string where instead of having **line breaks (/n)** I get a single whitespace.

I get:

`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- KOSKODKSOAKD DOKSODKSAOD...`

what I actually need:
`-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\nKOSKODKSOAKD\nDOKSODKSAOD...` (note the **/n**).

*Why I need this?*
Without it, the public key verification/validation will fail.
Now I have a function that runs through the string and manually adds the line breakers, but it ain't pretty, if I could make it work from the docker-compose file it would be much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

environment:
key=value

is a mapping with one key `environment`, which has as value `key=value`. That is not further parsed, `=` not having special meaning within YAML ( of course your application can further interpret such a scalar )

If you want list syntax in your block-style YAML, you'll need to use the block sequence entry indicator followed by a space (`-` ):

```
environment:
  - key=value
```

again `key=value` is a single scalar for YAML.

To set the environment variable `DEBUG`, the [docker-compose documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#set-environment-variables-in-containers) uses:

```
web:
  environment:
    - DEBUG=1
```

The split into the environment variable name `DEBUG` and its value (`1`) is done by docker-compose. If you want an environment variable to have newlines, you'll need the complete sequence element to be a multiline scalar, which you can do in the following way:

```
environment:
    - key=value
    - key2=value2
    - |-
      publicKey=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
      UAdhusaudu89Ajdsdoskdosadk*(Sd98798da
      kaosdkOKdoksaoKDOaksdo98d7868sadajidas
```

Comment: My error was trying to use the pipe `|` after `=` just like I used after `:`. kkkkrying. Thank you!

Comment: When you do that, YAML will just consider it being a multi-line unquoted scalar, not interpreting the `=` nor the `|`. Such a scalar is loaded with all consecutive whitespace (including newlines) converted to a single space in the loaded data.

Answer (score 0):

Here you get help:

[How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3790454/how-do-i-break-a-string-in-yaml-over-multiple-lines)

Use >- or |- instead if you don't want a linebreak appended at the end.

Comment: `>-` and `|-` only works when using `Mapping syntax` unfortunatelly. And I can't change the file.